# Passing a variable through post

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am trying to create a system to record sales. What I need is when the user clicks submit it sends the cost of the item over for the database entry. I already have the variable for the cost 'Product_Price' but for the sales table I need it to send with the form as 'sales_price' I tried to disable the box but then it just sales the box is null and doesn't work.

```
<form name="purchase" id="purchase" action="files/insert.php" method="post">
Name : <input type="text" name="sale_name" value="" />

Contact Details: <input type="text" name="sale_contact" value="" />

Address: <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="sale_address" value="">  </textarea>

Price: <input type="text" name="sale_price"  value="<?php echo $data['Product_Price'];?>" />  
<input type="submit" name="purchase" /></form>
```

Comment: Items in the form should appear in the `$_POST` array of insert.php. Basic PHP. Really basic PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correct, all you need is use `type="hidden"` on price input.

Answer (score 0):

try this price should not be edited mainly. So add readonly at last in the input

```
Price: <input type="text" name="sale_price"  value="<?php echo $data['Product_Price'];?>" readonly>
```

use `$_POST['sale_price']` to get value

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you should organize your inputs inside a fieldset, as explained on the W3Schools website [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). This will send the values from all inputs at once. On the receiving page (wherever you will be processing the values you send, either the same page or another one), you can check to see if they have sent values and, if so, tell what to do with them, like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['sales-price'])) {
$salesPrice = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['sales-price']); }
```

The code above not only processes the value that was sent, but it sanitizes it and assigns its value to a variable that you can then use in your code, like this:

```
<?php echo $salesPrice; ?>
```

The fieldset alone may solve your problem. Let me know if this helps.